# Can not run app using fcgi of perl Dancer

Tags: perl, fastcgi, dancer

I am testing to deploy the tester example of Dancer using fcgi. But it just didn't work.
I keep getting the error message:

```
File does not exist: /home/tester/MyApp/public/dispatch.fcgi/
```

However, this app can run successfully with cgi. And I have made the changes to http.conf according to dancer's deployment manual.

Can someone pointing me to some solutions or possible reasons for this error?

below is the http.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    # /srv/www.example.com is the root of your
    # dancer application
    DocumentRoot /home/tester/MyApp/public

    ServerAdmin you@example.com

    <Directory "/home/tester/MyApp/public">
       AllowOverride None
       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias / /home/tester/MyApp/public/dispatch.fcgi/

    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/MyApp-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/MyApp-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a file called `dispatch.fcgi` in that directory ?

Comment: Yes. as I mentioned that I was using Dancer's testing example which was created by "dancer -a MyApp". And there is "dispatch.fcgi" in /MyApp/public/

Comment: according to the error it needs to be in `/home/tester/MyApp/public`

Comment: it is in /home/tester/MyApp/public, I omitted the first part in my response.

Comment: Is there really a / at the end of the error message?  If so, something might be misconfigured.

Comment: yes, there is a "/" at the end of the error message. I c&p the error message from log. I add http.conf for your information. It actually worked well when I used cgi, but errors occured when I changed it to fcgi as Dancer::Deployment illustrated.

Comment: Could that be a typo in the documentation? In the section [Running as a cgi-script (or fast-cgi) under Apache](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Dancer-1.3120/lib/Dancer/Deployment.pod#Running_as_a_cgi-script_%28or_fast-cgi%29_under_Apache), the `ScriptAlias` directive in the CGI example uses a trailing slash but it later says to use this for FCGI: `ScriptAlias / /srv/www.example.com/public/dispatch.fcgi` (with no trailing slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that ScriptAlias is what you want to be using. From the documentation...

> The [ScriptAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) directive has the same behavior as the Alias
>   directive, except that in addition it marks the target directory as
>   containing CGI scripts that will be processed by mod_cgi's cgi-script
>   handler.

Basically Apache looks for a directory called '/home/tester/MyApp/public/dispatch.fcgi/' and every file in this dir is processed through mod_cgi. In this case it can't be found since it's a regular file.

Have you tried using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)? My httpd config for Dancer is pretty much the same as yours except I'm using mod_rewrite

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/src/MyApp/public
<Directory "/home/user/src/MyApp/public">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi #using fcgid instead of fastcgi
</Directory>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dispatch.fcgi$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you Gordolio. You method works like a charm. I just need to enable module using "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and used your config. It works!

Comment: That's great! Yeah, I think I may let the Dancer team know that they should update their documentation. I'm curious to know how many of them are using some sort of fast cgi with apache.There's also an issue that I need to send their way with request.uri_base not working. If you have issues with it, let me know and I can point you in the direction on how to fix it.

Comment: Sure, I'll let you know if I come into the same issues.